# How to record the live audio in the background in Android?

Tags: android, audio

In my application i'm recording live audio and playing it. The process is working in a thread.
In my code i'm using recorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(1000); 
and i found that this particular code is running in the main thread so that 
i cant access to other controls and found the app is getting stucked. 
What should i do to make this code to work in the background?

Comment: you should attach some piece of code. Your explanation is not very clear. You said that,it works in a thread so how it is possible that it runs also in UI thread.  Give some more informations